# Node.js does not include exported PATH from .bashrc

Tags: node.js, bash, path

In my .bashrc I have conda exported:

```
export PATH="$HOME/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

`conda` is working in a normal shell. But it is not working with `exec()` or `spawn()`. When printing the $PATH from node.js, the conda path is not included. In that case, I need to use the full path.

This is how I call the conda command and the script

```
// fails with conda ENOENT 
const p1 = spawn('conda');
// calling a bash script which uses conda command fails with
// stderr output of 'conda command not found'
const p2 = spawn('bash', ['setup.sh']);
```

How can I make node.js look at the .bashrc file for exported path, so I don't have to use the full path to the conda command?

Comment: The `~` will NOT be expanded in quotes. Use `$HOME` instead.

Comment: Ah, okay. I actually have /home/my_user in my .bashrc. I will edit the question. thanks.

Comment: Show how you are calling exec/spawn. You may have to spawn a shell to find it in your PATH: `spawn('sh', ['-c','conda -arg -arg'])`

Comment: Added an example. When using your suggestion it still fails to find conda, only the error output is now in stderr instead of on exit.

Comment: You're changing the question now : is setup.sh in the PATH? Is it executable?